# How to set index.php in the main page if you have it on another folder?

Tags: php, apache, indexing, directory, url-rewriting

I have a site I took from the web and modified it to fit my need, but the index page is in another folder rather than the `public_ftp` folder (controller view model), so, when any person enters the web address, they have to write: realestate/views for it to show. Is there a way to move the Index to the Public_ftp without messing all the work. I have moved it, but I get a lot of errors.

`Warning: include(header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealEstate1\index.php on line 2`

`Warning: include(): Failed opening 'header.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealEstate1\index.php on line 2`

`Warning: require_once(../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealEstate1\index.php on line 43`

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\RealEstate1\index.php on line 43`

This is the index.php code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php include'header.php';?>
<!-- banner -->
<div class="inside-banner">
  <div class="container"> 
    <span class="pull-right"><a href="index.php">Inicio</a> / Compra, Vende & Renta</span>
    <h2>Compra, Vende & Renta</h2>
</div>
</div>
<!-- banner -->


<div class="container">
<div class="properties-listing spacer">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 ">

  <div class="search-form">
    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Busca Propiedades</h4>
        <form action="search-result.php" method="get" class="form form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Busqueda por Nombre/Dirección">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
        </form>
  </div>



<div class="hot-properties hidden-xs"></div>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-8">
<div class="sortby clearfix">
<div class="pull-left result">Mostrando: Todas las Propiedades </div>

</div>
<div class="row">



    <?php
    require_once ('../vendor/autoload.php');
    use App\Classes\RealEstate\RealEstate;
    $real_estate = new RealEstate();
    $allData = $real_estate->index();

    foreach ($allData as $oneData){
        $image = explode(",",$oneData->images);
    ?>

     <!-- properties -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="properties">
        <div class="image-holder"><img src="../resources/images/properties/<?php echo $image[0];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="properties">
        </div>
        <h4><a href="property-detail.php?id=<?php echo $oneData->id;?>"><?php echo $oneData->name;?></a></h4>
        <p class="price">Price: $<?php echo $oneData->monthly_charges;?></p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="property-detail.php?id=<?php echo $oneData->id;?>">Ver Detalles
      </a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- properties -->
    <?php } ?>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php include'footer.php';?>
```

Comment: I think I got it, all I had to do was deleting this ../ from evey href=

Answer (score 0):

delete ../ from the path with the fatal error as it maps the links to the folder outside your home